# Nginx allow only my domain to access a video url

Tags: nginx, video, ffmpeg, html5-video, http-live-streaming

i'm setting up a web server that contains live video streaming embed into the html5 video tag. My workflow is to grab the rtsp video from an ip camera, decode it to a HLS format using ffmpeg and send the video to my server.
Nginx allows access to the video through a url, which I put in my video tag as a source.

Everything works perfectly, the only problem is that anyone can access the URL of the video and put that URL on their website without my permission.

Is there any way to only allow my domain to access, and block for example www.domain2.com to put it into their video tag or other framework thath they use? i'm think Nginx can do the job maybe.

Here are the codes of Nginx and my html in case is needed.

HTML:

```
<video id="player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered vjs-fluid"  controls preload="none">
<source src="//mydomain.com/live/stream.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
```

Nginx:

```
location /live {
            types {
                    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
            }
            limit_conn addr 5;
            alias /home/stream;
            add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    }
```

Many thanks guys!

Comment: What you are looking for is called CORS. https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

Answer (score -1):

If you have a fixed IP you could use the *allow* and *deny* command in nginx block, you could check how to use it here http://etapien.com/guides/nginx-allow-access-certain-ips/

```
location /live {
    types {
        application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
    }
    # .. some config

    allow 192.168.1.0/24; #your company subaddress
    allow 10.1.1.0/16;  #your company IP
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: This is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Hi Andrea, thanks for your answer, but this will restrict if someone with another ip tries to see my video in my website?, because i have a lot of visitors but i want them to see the video only form my website. Thanks!